# swig perl wrapper is not generating for class member functions

Tags: perl, swig

I have simple c++ class as below
//example.h

```
#include<iostream>
class example
{
public:
    int member;
    void display(){
        std::cout<<"Hello from example class"<<std::endl;
        }
};
```

//my example.i file is

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

after this I am running

> > pkgs/swig/2.0.8/bin/swig -c++ -perl5 example.i
> >     but I don't see a wrapper defined for my display function in .pm module thus generated.
> >     any working sample will be of great help.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 0):

even though I don't see a special wrapper for display method, I see something like below generated and it worked when i was trying to access it from perl

```
*display = *examplec::example_display;
```

my code to access the c++ class objects

```
use example;
$myObj =new example::example();
$myObj->{member} = 1000;
print $myObj->{member};
print "\n";
$myObj->display();
print "\nFinished";
```